# How to assign a class method to a default property (i.e. reference non-static methods from a static scope)

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have a plugin that has extendable transitions (used when new panels of data are shown). It comes with default transition methods of:

- "none" - just replace the data
- "slide" - slide out the existing panel and slide in the new one
- "fade" - fade out the existing panel then fade in the new one

The various transition methods all exist as properties of a `transitions` property on my default options object:

e.g.

```
module MyPlugins
{
    export class MyPlugin
    {
        static defaultOptions =
        {
            // Transition methods - can be extended to add new transitions
            transitions:
            {
                none: function (transition): JQueryPromise<any>
                {
                    return transition.$panel.toggle(transition.inward).promise();
                },
                slide: function (transition: TransitionEventParams): JQueryPromise<any>
                {
                    return this._slide(transition);
                },
                fade: function (transition: TransitionEventParams): JQueryPromise<any>
                {
                    return this._fade(transition);
                }
            }
        }

        // Greatly simplified example class method
        private _fade(transition: TransitionEventParams): JQueryPromise<any>
        {
            var $panel = transition.$panel;
            if (transition.inward)
            {
                return $panel.fadeIn(transition.duration).promise();
            }
            else
            {
                return $panel.fadeOut(transition.duration).promise();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At runtime the transition methods are called by name, using the plugin as the current `this`:

```
 promise = this.o.transitions[transition].call(this, transitionParams);
```

Now my question is: Is it possible to reference the class methods, from the static defaults, so that the anonymous function wrappers are not needed

e.g. I want to be able to have something like:

```
static defaultOptions =
{
    // Transition methods - can be extended to add new transitions
    transitions:
    {
        ...
        slide: MyPlugin._slide,
        fade: MyPlugin._fade
    }
```

But I can't figure out how to reference non-static class methods, except by name (e.g. `object["methodname"].call(this, params)`), from a static object.

Any ideas on how to simplify my default options? Should I just make the helper methods static too, given that the plugin will be the value of `this`?

Comment: You can try `MyPlugin.prototype._slide` - which statically accesses the "instance" method

Comment: @Bergi. That make sense and should have occurred to me. Do'h! Trying it out now... :)

Comment: @Bergi: Perfect. Works a treat. Please post as answer for me to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the "instance" methods statically on the prototype, like

```
transitions: {
    …
    slide: MyPlugin.prototype._slide,
    fade: MyPlugin.prototype._fade
}
```